# pandas read_html skipping a table

Tags: python, pandas

trying to read all tables from the url: 'https://www.citypopulation.de/php/netherlands-admin.php?adm2id=0363'
here is my code:

```
tables = pd.read_html(url)
print(len(tables))
```

it outputs 7 but the number of tables in the page are 8. in particular I am missing the nationwide table.

can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: You should print the ones you get and see in what they differ from the other one - HTML structure, placement within the document etc. Although, and I might be just missing something here, I only see 7 tables in your link.

Comment: you are right, that part is part of the first table, but again, by typing: tables , I don't see that part of the table extracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you want is in the first table of the document.

If you execute

print(tables[0])

You will be able to see it:

[image]